# Populate a Google Doc or HTML doc with Google Calendar data

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, google-calendar-api

I need to generate a Google Document from a Google Calendar (using date ranges if possible). In the Google Doc I  need to print:

date
event title
event description
link to event attachment

and repeat for all events in the date range

Any suggestion? I don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is far too broad and you can't get one answer for this and I'm not even sure this is a programming question.

Comment: Hi, Rob, I did not even know where to start. I'm less than a newbie on Google App Script. That's why I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to grab Google Calendar data and output it onto a web page.

I started at https://console.developers.google.com/ where I created service accounts. On the backend (C#) I sent the service account email address and loaded a certificate (the X509... classes) to contact the API (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview). There are other ways of authenticating, because I was processing this on the backend, this was easiest for me.

I then mapped the google model to my own local model, serialized it, and send it to the web page as JSON. Then I rendered my mustache-based template with the JSON data, and appended the output.

I suppose in your case, rather than rendering the data you might build an HTML string in some form from the data and save that to a new file using the Google Drive API (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) with probably a different service account.

I hope this helped.